# What level should a one-shot 5-round time travel magic item be?

Tags: dnd-4e, magic-items, homebrew, time-travel

I had a cool idea for a magic item for D&D 4th edition. Basically it would allow you to take your party's memories of the last 5 rounds and go back to your bodies of 5 rounds ago. It would be a one shot magic item and require a minor action to activate.

What level should it be?

Comment: This seems like it would lead to an incredible amount of pointless bookkeeping. "Where was everything 5 rounds ago? What was everybody's HP like? How long left on their conditions? What encounter / daily / cooldown abilities have they used?" - While it sounds like a fun gimmick, I think you might be underestimating just how much bookkeeping this thing is going to cost you.

Comment: i didn't think about that

Comment: So you want the [Dagger of Time](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4LUg8OFOQWk&t=42s)?

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like an Epic Level Artefact to me.

(Also sounds like a nightmare, considering you'd need at any point in time to be able to remember the state of all creatures of exactly 5 rounds ago)

Comment: thanks but I'm thinking you would only be able to use it once, like a potion.

Comment: @wyatt Even so in order to be prepared to use it you would have to make sure you kept the information available at all times. Unless you already use something that would be able to track this you will have quite a bit more bookkeeping.

Comment: Every time travel related magical effect of this type that I've seen either took steps to limit the scope of bookkeeping required (only one round of travel, only the user's condition is 'reset,' using the device causes fluctuations in reality that changes everyone's condition anyway, it only takes you back to when you were in perfect condition, etc.) or somehow allowed the GM to choose a specific destination time, in order to pick one with known details.